# Instagram api - search users

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I work on application with Instagram API. Today I have problem with searching users. This query return always only one record.

I use this: (I cut out client id..)

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?count=50&q=test&client_id=myID
```

or

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=test&client_id=myID
```

But still get same result:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"username":"test","profile_picture":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/t51.2885-19\/10483581_1498221113789874_1762363890_a.jpg","id":"44291","full_name":"julian"}]}
```

Yesterday same query returns 50 users. I do not see any changelog about this in Instagram API. Do you know where is problem?

Comment: And when I test website like this: http://websta.me/search/test the result is also 50 users..

Comment: today, it works right again

Comment: This URL work for me . 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=jack&access_token=***

Comment: now in 2023,  could you please suggest which Instagram API should I choose for search Instagram users and their data like instanavigation.com Should I choose graph API or basic display API? I am using Next.js

Answer (score 7):

Instagram retired the users/search endpoint.

When you call `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=john&access_token=TOKEN-HERE` now, you get this response:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 400,
        "error_type": "APINotAllowedError",
        "error_message": "This endpoint has been retired"
}
```

Comment: i dont think this is an answer because its 20 Nov 2018 and i only received the error ("This endpoint has been retired") today how did you get this fixed the first time?

Comment: In 2023, could you please suggest which Instagram API should I choose for search Instagram users and their data like instanavigation.com Should I choose graph API or basic display API? I am using Next.js

Answer (score 1):

Please see instagram user search api
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search

You need to pass additional "count" param to set number of result in response.

See the image : 
 [Instagram user search api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDBOw.png)

Comment: In 2023, could you please suggest which Instagram API should I choose for search Instagram users and their data like instanavigation.com Should I choose graph API or basic display API? I am using Next.js

Answer (score 1):

The Instagram API is now managed by Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery

It is unclear how to search users though.

Comment: In 2023,  could you please suggest which Instagram API should I choose for search Instagram users and their data like instanavigation.com Should I choose graph API or basic display API? I am using Next.js